# Gutenberg's press by different design

Tags: publishing

Johannes Gutenberg used a wine press to press paper against the metal type. Was this the only technological option available to him or were there any other options available at the time? It just makes some sense to me because there has to have other devices that could have done the job of inspiring him.

Comment: I don't understand how the edit makes it any less opinion-based? "He could have used X or Y because of a, b, or c" is still an opinion. If there's actual evidence that he considered using some other technology but ended up choosing the wine press, that's great, but "did he have options" is still rather broad.

Comment: @verbose It's a question asking about alternatives that were available at the time, which is a perfectly fact-based question. It does not ask what went through Gutenberg's mind, which would be speculative (unless  we have a diary or letters actually documenting this type of information).

Comment: The edit makes less opinion based but turns it into an open ended list with no answer being more valid than the other. Much like "are there any books that have xyz plot element".questions.

Comment: @Skooba I don't understand how this can be an open-ended list. How many technologies have effectively been used for printing before the advent of industrialisation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There has been speculation that the design of the Gutenberg press may have been inspired by the [binder's nipping press](https://www.philobiblon.com/suppliers.shtml) since the codex form was well-established before the arrival of Gutenberg's press.